# SSH pub key add to authorized key

Tags: ssh-keys

How to add public key to servers authorized_keys file if i use it on Windows (cat command does not work simply) and i know how to add with scp command or with sftp and it's work fine but the problame is this is overwrite the current keys to new. I would like to add an secound key and i want to do it on secure.

I tred it but it dont find the directory root.

> C:>type C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw "password" "cat >> Users/User/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Comment: I'm a Linux person, so can't answer it definitively, but SSH keys are text. You can open it, copy, paste and save in a plain text editor (like notepad)

Comment: Yes it is work perfectly. Just i want to know how to do with ssh. when use SSH layer protocols it overwrite it instead of paste it on the following line.
But i can solve it as you suggested. Unfortunately i need to use ssh for copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**
How to add public key to a remote linux servers authorized_keys file from a Windows batch file using plink (putty utility).

**Problem:**
The below command fails with a path not found error

> plink -ssh [USERNAME]@[DOMAIN] -pw [PASSWORD] cat .ssh/keyfile.pub >>
> .ssh/authorized_keys

as you suspected the forward slash / and > are special characters in windows.  They're being interpreted by the windows cmd session before being passed to plink.  So plink can't understand the path, nor the append command.

**Solution:**
you use another special character ^ or shift-6 to escape the problem characters in your batch file.  then the cmd shell won't interpret them and plink gets the command you intended.

> plink -ssh [USERNAME]@[DOMAIN] -pw [PASSWORD] cat .ssh^/keyfile.pub ^>^>
> .ssh^/authorized_keys

works great.